# Cannot inject AuthenticationController

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I am trying to inject a controller into my `app.run` function, however i keep getting:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.10/$injector/unpr?p0=AuthenticationControllerProvider%20%3C-%20AuthenticationController
```

Here's my `app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'AuthenticationModule'
]);

app.run(['$rootScope', 'AuthenticationService', 'AuthenticationController',
    function($rootScope, AuthenticationService, AuthenticationController) {

        console.log(AuthenticationController);
    }
]);
```

The `AuthenticationService` is injecting just fine. Why are `AuthenticationController` not being injected?

Comment: please provide the code where you define both services

Comment: I do not believe you can inject controllers into run blocks.

Comment: This is not possible in Angular. Why are you trying to inject a controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the [AngularJS documentation on modules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module):

> Run blocks - get executed after the injector is created and are used
>   to kickstart the application. **Only instances and constants** can be
>   injected into run blocks. This is to prevent further system
>   configuration during application run time.

In the [documentation for controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller), it states:

> In Angular, a Controller is a JavaScript **constructor function** that is
>   used to augment the Angular Scope. When a Controller is attached to
>   the DOM via the ng-controller directive, Angular will instantiate a
>   new Controller object, using the specified Controller's **constructor
>   function**.

A controller is an **instance constructor function**, not an instance itself, as opposed to a service, which is. Therefor, from what I can gather, controllers cannot be injected into a run block.

If you need to configure a controller at start-up time, then use a provider. As it turns out, in angular, controllers (along with directives, filters, and animations) are all simply syntactic sugar for a provider. Providers can be configured using configuration blocks: [configuration block documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

> **Configuration blocks** - get executed during the provider registrations
>   and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected
>   into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation
>   of services before they have been fully configured.